# Converting function in constructor to functional component in react class based component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-class-based-component

I am trying the convert class based component to the functional component.

I'm basically trying to connect to a socket and I couldn't come up with a solution on how to separate this function.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: "",
    };

    this.waitForSocketConnection(() => {
      WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks(
        this.setMessages.bind(this),
        this.addMessage.bind(this)
      );
      WebSocketInstance.fetchMessages();
    });
  }
  waitForSocketConnection(callback) {
    const component = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (WebSocketInstance.state() === 1) {
        console.log("Connection is made");
        callback();
        return;
      } else {
        component.waitForSocketConnection(callback);
      }
    }, 100);
  }
```

I used the function in useEffect (corresponding to componentDidMount), but I couldn't get the data from the socket. When I called the method directly in the functional component instead of useEffect, I saw messages coming, but for some reason, I don't know why, when the waitForSocketConnection method is called, it affects the ui and makes it unusable. I can't click anywhere in the ui.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    waitForSocketConnection(() => {
      WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks(setMessages, addMessage);
      WebSocketInstance.fetchMessages();
    });
  }, []);

  function waitForSocketConnection(callback) {
    const component = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (WebSocketInstance.state() === 1) {
        console.log("Connection is made");
        callback();
        return;
      } else {
        component.waitForSocketConnection(callback);
      }
    }, 100);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by removing 'this' from the waitForSocketConnection function. See below

```
  function waitForSocketConnection(callback) {
setTimeout(function () {
  if (WebSocketInstance.state() === 1) {
    console.log("Connection is made");
    callback();
    return;
  } else {
    waitForSocketConnection(callback);
  }
}, 100);}
```